# Comparar map<string,any> c++ 17

Tags: c++, algoritmo, c++17, stdclass

Não estou conseguindo comparar dois mapas .

Ex:

```
  map<string, any> columnsMap = {
      {"status", 1}, {"client_delivered", 0}, {"client_notification", 0}};
  map<string, any> columnsMap2 = {
      {"status", 1}, {"client_delivered", 0}, {"client_notification", 0}};
  if (columnsMap2 == columnsMap)
    std::cout << "algo" << std::endl;
```

Mensagem recebida:

```
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:449:51: note:   ‘const std::any’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::sub_match<_BiIter>’
[build]   449 |     { return __x.first == __y.first && __x.second == __y.second; }
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer essa comparação direta?

Olhando a documentação std::any não tem o operador [operator==] implementado

Comment: Já pesquisou sobre std::equal ?

Comment: @FourZeroFive já, a solução que encontrei foi usar std::variant em vez de any. Não é o que eu gostaria, mas é o mais sensato.